# Send data/string online to a device connected to the internet

Tags: networking, tcp, udp

Good Day,

I basically have a laptop connected to the internet with a fixed IP Address. I need to have a way for a server possibly though a PHP script, send data/string to the laptop and it is able to receive it.

Now, if I was within a local network, i could do that. But what if I wanted to send from an external network? Do devices have a particular address that I can access from any internet connection?

Answer (score 0):

> Do devices have a particular address that I can access from any
>   internet connection?

No, it does not, unless you do use external IP for your laptop (doubtfully).

The easiest and fastest solution I could think of is to do the other way round: open TCP or UDP socket on your server and use laptop to connect and request data from the server. Of course, it is not suitable for all scenarios, but in many cases it works. Write more information (what is the purpose of this? What are the requirements and limitations?) so more specific answer may be provided.

Comment: Okay I'll get straight to the point. I have a wifly chip that is connected to my router with internet access. I need this wifly chip to "listen" to my server and receive data/strings.

Comment: In this case, [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation), as @wookie919 mentioned, is the simplest solution. Just forward the port you are listening. Even the low-end routers have this feature nowadays. Of course, you should not forget security, as leaving such widely used ports as 80 or 8080 opened is not the safest way to go (but that's a different topic).

Answer (score 0):

OK, to make things easier to explain, let's say:
- Your router's public IP address is 10.10.10.10
- Your laptop's private IP address is 192.168.0.1
- You want to communicate via port 80 (since you mentioned PHP)

What you need to do is configure your router so that it forwards packets destined to 10.10.10.10:80 to 192.168.0.1:80. This is the simplest form of NAT.

Then from anywhere else with an Internet connection, you can send packets to your laptop by sending packets to 10.10.10.10:80.

Comment: ..it's only a case if laptop stays at home connected to the same router.

Comment: Yes, I assumed this. If the laptop is taken to various places, then I guess the simplest option would be to use 3G Internet connections or similar so that the laptop itself has a public IP address.